# What's a good self-contained GeoIP solution for rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, ip-geolocation

We're currently using [geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/) to determine our users' countries of origin, but we're concerned about the volumens of queries we're going to generate.  Since most of our visitors are one-offs, just caching the results isn't sufficient; we need something with its own look-up table.  Is there a freely available database we can pull from every so often?  Or is there an alternative we haven't considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947172/what-is-the-best-provider-of-geoip-data) we went with [MaxMind GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) which has a free IP-to-country map downloadable in CSV format.  Apparently it has some issues with AOL users but it's been good enough for our purposes so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) ?

Comment: I think Simon is looking for a way to determine country by IP address. I took a quick look at the Geonames docs and it doesn't look like it does this. Please correct me if I am wrong.